# using R in PHP and not having to reload R packages

Tags: php, mysql, r

I have an existing system with data in MySQL and program logic in PHP. I would like to effectively use R to support statistical requirements.

A brief background on the legacy system which needs improvement is:

1. build .R script files to run specific functions [using PHP].
2. export data from mySQL to CSV files [using PHP]
3. run exec () commands in PHP to run R commands via command prompt
       a. read data from CSV
       b. perform R operations
       c. write output to output files
4. read output from output files [in PHP]

The above mentioned system has obvious **problems that I need help with**:
**1)** poor performance due to 'unclean' data exchange via MySQL to PHP to CSV files to R. --> solution, I think, is using the [RMySQL](http://www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-mysql-through-r/) package.

**2)** running multiple R commands via PHP exec() command requires R libraries to reload every time a command is run. This is a performance drain.

**I will greatly appreciate** any suggestions on how to improve the system OR advice on solving problem 2) OR advice on alternative ways to integrate MySQL, PHP and R effectively.

Thanks!